# How do I check 3 Lists if they contain the same number

Tags: shell

I have a quick question:I am supposed to write a Shellscript script in which i can put 3 parameters and then the script is supposed to look through these 3 Lists and pick out the numbers that identical.I went ahead and wrote this script but i can not really get it to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

Parameter1=${1}
Parameter2=${2}
Parameter3=${3}

for var in $Parameter3; do
 for var2 in $Parameter2; do
  if [ $var == $var2 ]; then
   for var3 in $Parameter; do
    if [ $var2 == $var3 ]; then
     echo $var3
    fi
   done
  fi
 done
done
```

Comment: Please edit your Q to show a sample run of your script, and the expected output, your current output and the exact text o any error messages. I'd also recommend pasting your script into https://shellcheck.net and fix any errors flagged there (there will be some).  Good luck.

Comment: For starters, the shell is white-space sensitive. The `[` command (yes it is the `test` command) needs white-space to the left and right of it. Next, the string equality operator is `=`, not `==` (even though some shells cater to this common error and accept `==` as well). The numeric equality operator is `-eq`.

Comment: As @Jens has already mentioned, some white-space would really help with readability here (and it would also probably fix some errors further down the line). I suggested an edit that is easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the simplest way would be to add a `space` at the beginning and end of `Paremeter2` and `Parameter3` so you can loop over the numbers in `Parameter1` and use `[[...]]` with the `=~` operator to check if the current number from `Parameter1` exits in both `Parameter2` and `Parameter3` in a single complex command within a single loop, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

Parameter1=${1:-"1 3 5 7 9 11 13"}         ## default numbers if no arguments provided
Parameter2=${2:-"0 4 11 21"}
Parameter3=${3:-"6 11 16 21 26"}

Parameter2=" $Parameter2 "                 ## add space before/after 2 & 3
Parameter3=" $Parameter3 "

common=                                    ## empty common value variable

for i in $Parameter1; do                   ## loop over numbers in 1
    ## compare with numbers in 2 and 3
    [[ $Parameter2 =~ " $i " ]] && [[ $Parameter3 =~ " $i " ]] && {
        common=$i                          ## set common value, if found
        break
    }
done

echo "common $common"
```

By adding the `space` at the beginning and end of `Parameter2` and `Parameter3` you can use `" $i "` as a regular expression to determine if that number exists in `Parameter2` and `Parameter3` with:

```
[[ $Parameter2 =~ " $i " ]] && [[ $Parameter3 =~ " $i " ]]
```

Much easier that attempting 3-nested loops.

**Example Use/Output**

With the script above saved as `common-of-3.sh`, you would do:

```
$ bash common-of-3.sh
common 11
```

`11` being common to all three parameters. You can add a check of `[ -z "$common" ]` and to test if there is no match and output whatever you like.

Let me know if you have further questions.